# After `git pull` command execution git has some files modified, which were not modified

Tags: git

I have a project in git. I made some changes and tried to commit and push. Somebody did some changes in the same file as me, so I had to pull the changes and resolve these changes manually. After that I add merging conflict solution by command "add" I have files in commit, which I hadn't modified.

I haven't noticed these changes and pushed them to the repository with my modifications too. After it my project is somehow broken (it has bugs).

I am quite new to git, so I need help to resolve the issue. What is the right solution for this situation?

**EDIT** I noticed in my terminal history, that commit with files which I hadn't changed appeared after pull command execution.

Comment: `git pull --rebase` is your friend. Also you (and your team) should read up on branching.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen thanks !

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen unfortunately didn't work. Since I pushed these changed to the master branch

Comment: You can rewrite history, using `git rebase -i master`. `git pull --rebase` would have worked before pushing, you should really read up on git before using it ... it can be a dangerous tool if you do not understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw the comment and second it. In your situation, `git pull --rebase` will do what you're asking.

Read about rebasing here http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: I checked this command and it didn't help, since I already pushed my local changes + some other to the repository